# Validating Unique Keys for Unit Testing using Effort

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-database-first, effort

I'm currently doing a POC for Unit Testing in an existing solution. I have been reading here and there and one library I saw that I found very interesting to do tests that involve Entity Framework is Effort (https://effort.codeplex.com/).

During my first tests, Effort has been good to simulate my Database context, no weird errors were thrown, most of the operations were good, like adding a new record and incrementing my primary key when a table has identity, good at that moment, until I reached a situation that involved a table that has a Unique Key.

This is my current scenario:

1. A Database first model.
2. The context nor the Entity doesn't have the unique key rule, so if Effort works "In Memory" the unique key must exist in the code so Effort takes it in the process, so I added the Unique Key in my entity manually just to test it, I added it in three attributes (fields) in my Class (Entity):

   [Index("UK_WhateverName", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]

   [Index("UK_WhateverName", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]

   [Index("UK_WhateverName", IsUnique = true, Order = 3)]
3. The method has inside a try catch, inside the try is the dbcontext.SaveChanges(). In real conditions a DbUpdateException is captured when the Unique Key rule is infringed, so when that happens the method returns a -1.
4. I assumed that even if Effort is able to capture the unique key failure it probably won't throw a DbUpdateException, so I added an additional catch to capture Exception, any exception that could happen.
5. The code is working fine in real conditions, the -1 is being returned when the unique key is infringed.

The current outcome using Effort is that the code passes without any problems, it doesn't capture the unique key failure, not even within the Exception catch, and the test saves it normally incrementing the primary key.

Is it possible in Effort to simulate Unique Key failures?, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to that?